# Publishing multiple iOS apps using different developer accounts

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I need to upload 2 different apps on the App Store using 2 different Apple developer accounts.

Does Apple monitors what apps upload from the same Mac? Can I run into any troubles? Does this interfere with apps review?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The question you've written is very hard to understand could you please try rewording the question to make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: @unknowndomain For example I have app with name `firstApp` and app `secondApp`. Also I have two different apple developer accounts. I want to upload `firstApp` on first developer account. And `secondApp` on another developer account. I upload this apps from same `MacBook Pro`. Apple will pay attention to the fact that my apps were sent from one `MacBook Pro` to different developer accounts? Will I have problems while reviewing? Can Apple regard this like spam?

Comment: I don't have the answer to that, however Apple has been very tough on developers in the past where one of their accounts had a violation the other accounts were also suspended for violations, so while I doubt they'd see it as spam, if there was an issue where you deliberately violated their rules you could see issues. https://www.engadget.com/2016/10/10/apple-suspends-developer-account-over-review-fraud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Apple monitors what apps upload from the same Mac?

**No**.

> Can I run into any troubles?

**No**.

> Does this interfere with apps review?

**No**.

You should be absolutely fine given that you have proper distribution certificates setup for both the accounts and you use the correct ones while creating the app archive and publishing them.

Publishing apps for different account is a routine activity performed by freelancers and companies engaged in offering bespoke iOS development services.